# Show phpDoc warnings in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt, phpdoc

I use Eclipse PDT and phpDoc.

I would like the warnings of phpDoc to show up in the editor, just like other "validation" tools. This would help the programmer team to create better documentation.

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a useful tool for enforcing coding standards in PHP called [PHP CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected).

It includes prebuilt rules to enforce docblock requirements.  I'm sure if the provided rules aren't exactly what you need it would be relative easy to extend your own rules.

There's a prebuilt integration with Eclipse that includes some other tools like phpunit at [PhpSrc](http://www.phpsrc.org/)

I've used these tools to enforce coding standards with good results.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing finally ;). PhpSrc rocks, and I used some of PEAR's coding guidelines for validating PHP docblocks (they have a set of CodeSniffer rules).